# How viewstate is manage behind the scene in asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, webforms, viewstate

in asp.net web form we always work with server controls and we know that server controls state is maintain by **viewstate**.i have few question on asp.net net engine internal state management technique as follows....

**1)** what is the meaning of control state....give some example. if we put data in any textbox and postback occur and when page come back to server then data still persist in textbox even if we disable viewstate for that page. so which controls state is maintain through viewstate ?

**2)** i really do not know how asp.net webform engine maintain controls state through viewstate ? so guide me in such a way as a result i can understand how controls state is maintain through viewstate and also tell me name of those controls whose state is maintain through viewstate ?

**3)** how asp.net engine render & read back data from viewstate and re-populate controls at server end ?

**4)** we know viewstate is encrypted data but before encryption how data looks like ?

**5)** i want to disable viewstate for my whole web site and i want to develop my own viewstate management technique which will render viewsate in page for all controls state management and when postback occur then i want to develop a routine which will read controls state from viewstate and repopulate controls state. is there any article exist for custom viewstate management technique which i can use in my project and i can disable built-in viewstate for the whole project.

[Custom View state provider example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8001/ViewState-Provider-an-implementation-using-Provide)

the above link talk about custom ViewState Provider but i guess if i disbale built-in viewstate for whole page then the above provider may not work.

Comment: Are you sure that your viewstate will be better than the microsoft designed one? (saying about your point 5). View state is not really a bad idea, but being misused.

Comment: This blog post is probably the best you can get for understanding viewstate http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx